# Using angle pairs and geometry, find all the missing angles.

Tags: geometry

Apologies for the bland title.

I ran across this problem in my Geometry test this morning. It really stumped me as I couldn't really gather a starting point. Attached is a rendering of the problem, with the same angles and lines. Not drawn to scale though. Any help is appreciated! For context, I am a freshman.

Blue rightfully pointed out that I should mention what I did to try to solve the problem. My first thought was to use the interior angles theorem to find angle B, which comes out to 77°. Using a vertical angle, we can deduce that the angle left to angle A, has to also be 77°. Thus that creates a linear pair to which we can find angle A. 180-77=103. Using a corresponding angle, angle A = angle E. So angle E must also be 103°. I believe that angle E and D have to equal 180° so angle D is 77°. That creates a linear pair so angle C must be 103°.

Now what is really messing me up is how to find angle G. I couldn't find a good start. Thank you for the advice :)

[image]

Comment: Use $1.$ Vertically opposite angles are equal  $2.$  Exterior angle in a triangle is equal to sum of two interior angle.  $3.$ Corresponding angles in two parallel lines are equal   $4.$ Sum of all the angles of a quadrilateral is $360$ degrees and other basics geometric results.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc). This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you aren't familiar. (Note that "I have no idea" typically gets interpreted unfavorably as "Do my homework for me".) Since your exercise is from a test, presumably you have *some* idea of what "angle pairs and geometry" are needed to solve it; say so.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! ... Now, you cannot find $\angle B$ using "interior angles" (presumably, "Interior angles on the same side of a transversal between parallel lines are supplementary"); that would require the "top" and "bottom" lines to be *parallel*, which they aren't (because they meet at the left). This throws off your calculation of $\angle A$. (Likewise, $\angle D$ and $\angle E$ are not supplementary.) Moreover, $A$ and $E$ are not "corresponding angles", since they do not have a common transversal as a side.

Comment: Since there's a lot going on here, it helps to take things in stages. ... First, look for "vertical angles" and mark all as-yet-unmarked angles you can identify. (That is, mark the angle opposite $154^\circ$ with "$154^\circ$", and the one opposite $A$ with "$A$", and the one opposite $G$ with "$G$", etc. You should mark ten angles this way.) ... Then, mark supplementary "linear pairs". (For instance, the angles next to $154^\circ$ are each $26^\circ$; there are a couple of $77^\circ$s and a couple of $42^\circ$s; the neighbors of $G$ are $180^\circ-G$.) (continued)

Comment: (continued) Now that every angle has a name, start looking for more interesting connections. ... There's a triangle with angles $A$, $26^\circ$, $77^\circ$; does that tell you anything? ... Also, looking at the actually-parallel lines: along the "upper" transversal, you have, for instance, corresponding angles $A$ and (newly-marked) $C$, and others; along the "lower" transversal, you have, say, corresponding angles $F$ and (recently-calculated) $77^\circ$. And so forth. ... See how far this gets you.

Comment: (Thanks! :) ... Please update your question with any new work you've done, so that we can witness your progress. Even better: post your own answer with a complete solution that we can upvote in celebration.